# How to write app.yaml file for PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I am currently working on a PHP Web application for GAE using Cloud SQL as well. I have problems when deploying the PHP App to GAE.

The ERROR message is `"Error: Not FoundThe requested URL / was not found on this server."`.

I tried to follow some sample **app.yaml** files, none work. The application works perfectly fine in my local. I suspect I wrote the **app.yaml**, I am new to the .yaml file and whole google app engine, please help.

I tried with

```
handlers:
  url: .*
  script: index.php and it gives me too many redirects error.
```

I changed to script: **login-view.php** (my login page instead) the login page shows but I am unable to login as it does not authenticate properly.

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: login-view.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php

env_variables:
    MYSQL_DSN: "mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<instance name>;dbname=<dbname>"
    MYSQL_USER: "username"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "<instance name>"
```

When I launch my browser:

```
Able to launch the login page but now login-view.php error 

 appspot.com redirected you too many times.
 Try clearing your cookies.
 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Comment: I ran both of your attempted app.yaml configurations and they worked as expected using sample 'hello world apps'. Could you share a code snippet of 'index.php'? It would help me understand what is going on in that file, and whether something could have caused an unneeded redirect. On a last note, remember it's the instance connection name you have to use to establish the connection, not the instance name itself (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#setting-up-sql-instance).

Comment: Hi William thanks for your comment. I think the above works for hello world app as there are no other php pages. After several trial and error my app worked.

` handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php `

Answer (score 3):

After several trial and errors this worked for multiple .php pages

```
handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```